# Classical conditioning paradigm for hippocampal learning

Tags: neuroscience, learning, memory, measurement, methodology

I wanted to know what a suitable classical conditioning experiment would be to analyze learning and memory capabilities in rodent models with respect to hippocampal long-term potentiation (LTP).

For example, I want to subject the animal to conditioning and test the behavioral readout at a certain time point after conditioning. Many , like fear conditioning experiments, are mostly attributed to amygdala processes.

I wish to know some classical conditioning task where I can understand primarily hippocampal processes.

Also is there a way to monitor hippocampal CA1-CA3 firing pattern after the training period or during the training ?

That is, I want to check if LTP will sustain after the training period or is there is any increased sustenance of LTP post training.

But if I am to do this electrophysiological experiment in hippocampal brain slices, how will I incorporate the conditioned and unconditioned aspect to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Read this paper

**Storage of Spatial Information by the Maintenance Mechanism of LTP**

Eva Pastalkova*, Peter Serrano*, Deana Pinkhasova, Emma Wallace, André Antonio Fenton†, Todd Charlton Sacktor†
http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5790/1141.short

It uses a conditioning task that is primarily hippocampal as it is a spatial navigation task.  They monitor the strength of CA3-CA1 connections during and after training using the fEPSP (field excitatory post-synaptic potential) slope.

Also, for a review of hippocampal dependent tasks, see

**The role of hippocampal subregions in memory for stimulus associations**

Rosamund F. Langston, Cassie H. Stevenson, Claire L. Wilson, Ian Saunder, Emma R. Wood

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166432810004857